# Nodejs: Exec from child_process returns bin/sh: 1: command not found but works when writing manually in terminal?

Tags: javascript, node.js, linux, raspberry-pi

Using Node.js to automatically execute command in the terminal on raspberry pi, tho it wont work with exec(command). It outputs bin/sh: 1: command not found when trying to catch the output. But the command works when writing the command manually in the terminal?

Why is that?

```
async function run_command_fuel() {
    const command = "weconnect-cli PASSWORDINFORMATION get /vehicles/SECRETNUM/domains/fuelStatus/rangeStatus/primaryEngine/remainingRange_km";
   
    let returnval = 0;

    let child = exec(command);


    await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        child.stdout.on('data', function(data) {
            console.log('stdout: ' + data);
            returnval = data;
            console.log(returnval);
            resolve();
        });
        child.stderr.on('data', function(data) {
            console.log('stderr: ' + data);
            reject();
        });
        child.on('close', function(code) {
            console.log('closing code: ' + code);
        });
    })

    return returnval;

}
```

Comment: maybe show the js code you're running so we can help debug?

Comment: Just added the code

Answer (score 3):

Running the exec command creates a new shell, which wont have the same environment as your node process. You will need to specify the `PATH` environment variable in order to use that command.

Node gives you a way to do this through the object you pass in the exec command, as the second parameter, which defaults to `process.env`.

To pass in the object:

```
const command = "weconnect-cli PASSWORDINFORMATION get /vehicles/SECRETNUM/domains/fuelStatus/rangeStatus/primaryEngine/remainingRange_km";

let child = exec(command, {env: {'PATH': 'path/to/command'}});
```

Another way you can do this is through standard shell env setting before a command. You can modify your command to this:

```
const env_vars = 'PATH=' + 'path/to/command' + ' ';
const command = "weconnect-cli PASSWORDINFORMATION get /vehicles/SECRETNUM/domains/fuelStatus/rangeStatus/primaryEngine/remainingRange_km";

let child = exec(env_vars + command);
```

Comment: This just leaves me with Traceback (most recent call last) at the location. Its an output from stderr. Is this because i use the wrong method to catch the output from terminal?